# aws ec2 install git server

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, ubuntu

I tried to set up git server
AWS-EC2 AMI ubuntu-16.04
login-as:ubuntu

```
ubuntu@~$su
root@~#apt install git-core
root@~#adduser git
root@~#cd /
root@/#mkdir git
root@/#chmod 777 git
root@/#cd git 
root@/git#mkdir .ssh
root@/git#git init --bare test.git
root@/git#chown -R git:git test.git
```

client : windows7 git

```
$ssh-keygen
$cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh  ubuntu@public ip "cat >> /home/ubuntu/.ssh/authorized_keys"
```

server ubuntu-16.04
root@/#cp /home/ubuntu/.ssh/authorized_keys /git/.ssh/authorized_keys

client: windows7 git

```
$git clone git@public ip:/git/test.git
git@public ip: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

WHY?
I'm at VMware workstations ubuntu-16.04 was a success
Give me a hand, please. Thank you

Comment: see if you can relate: http://trialstravails.blogspot.com/2016/03/git-server-setup-on-amazon-aws.html

Answer (score 0):

can you please verify if public SSH key has been associated with your GIT Account. you can verify the same under your profile settings in your [git account](https://github.com/settings/keys)

Comment: looks like you have used default path and default account as /home/ubuntu/.ssh/authorized_keys . you can create a new user and add public key to its ~/.ssh/authorized_keys doing this you should be able to login to you instance with original key pair

Answer (score 0):

aws ec2 ubuntu-16.04
Default normal account ubuntu was a success